# Constructing objects with functions as a means of dependency injection

Tags: c#, function, dependency-injection

I stumbled across some code and I was curious as to possible reasons why it would be this way.

There are two constructors, the main one being called in code and the second one being used in testing for dependency injection. The second constructor accepted a function that returns the object rather than an instance of the object itself.

```
MainConstructor()  
:this(() => Factory.Current.GetInstance<IQueryService>()){ 
}

SecondConstructor(Func<IQueryService> getQueryService){
}
```

I was curious as to advantages you would get from passing in a function instead of an instance.

Comment: what a strange way to do Dependency Injection.

Comment: Understand that the parameterless constructor you have created is not strictly dependency injection; it's service location with IoC, which couples your code to the IoC container and is usually considered an anti-pattern for that reason (dependency injection can be done without an IoC framnework; a service locator can't be removed from code dependent on it without major refactoring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are several possible benefits for doing something like this:**

1. **Decoupling**: By allowing the caller to pass in a delegate rather than an instance, both the caller and the callee (in your case the class being constructed) can be decoupled from the object being passed and where it comes from.
2. **Lazy Acquisition**: By passing in a delegate, the instance can be acquired in a lazy manner. In other words, the constructor could in principle cache the delegate and call it at the last possible moment, only when an instance is actually needed. If the instance is never needed, it may never get created.
3. **Recreatability**: By passing in a delegate rather than an instance, the class can cache the mechanism used to create a query service on demand. In this way, the delegate acts as a factory, allowing instances of the type needed to be created on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Func<T>` allows the product to be lazily created which is useful for optional dependencies - for example one of the classes methods may look like this:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    if(someCondition)
    {
        IQueryService service = this.getQueryService();
        service.Execute():
    }
}
```

If `IQueryService` is expensive to create this could improve efficiency if `someCondition` never evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

The `Func<IQueryService>` is in this case really an abstract factory in disguise. So the question really is: "why would you want to use a factory instead of injecting the object itself?"

You use a factory when the lifetime of such instance matters to the consumer, you need to control the lifetime of that instance, or the instance is expensive to create. Good example of this is when objects implement `IDisposable`. Disposable objects often need to be controlled explicitly.

I'm personally not fond of using `Func<T>` delegates as factories, because it makes your code less explicit. Rather than depending on a `Func<IQueryService>`, let the class depend on an `IQueryServiceFactory`. This makes your code much more explicit. Downside of this approach is of course that you will have to write more code (not much, but still).

The second constructor uses the Dependency Injection pattern. The first constructor however, is an example of [Poor Man's DI](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner.aspx). It's a way of allowing to inject dependencies for the sake of unit testing, but saving you the need to use a dependency injection framework for your production code. A downside of this approach is the need for a dependency on the container (the `Factory` class in your case), a pattern which is called [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx). Another downside is that it makes the needed dependencies of a class less obvious.